# Openpyxl: iterate through all rows of one column

Tags: python, openpyxl

I have a worksheet file with 2 columns and thousands of rows. I want to iterate through all rows but grab only the first column.

This prints out every column, how to print e.g. only 'A':

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook

workbook = load_workbook('file.xlsx')
sheet = workbook['Table1']

for row in sheet:
    for cell in row:
        print(sheet[cell.coordinate].value)
```

Got it running like this, but is there a more efficient way without the comparison clause?

```
for row in sheet:
    for cell in row:
        if cell.coordinate[0] == 'A':
            print(sheet[cell.coordinate].value)
```

Comment: What's wrong with `ws['A']`?

Answer (score 1):

Using dataframe it could be simpler and should run faster:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel('file.xlsx', sheet_name="Table1")
print(df.iloc[:,[0]])
```

Performance testing for Loading a somehow big excel file using openpyxl vs pandas (to provide PoC of my above statement and to provide some actual test results to reply to Charlie Clark's comment below). It is solely for the purpose of learning and knowledge sharing with each other than any other reason.

**Preparing a Big File**:

```
import openpyxl as xl
wb = xl.Workbook()
ws = wb['Sheet']
wb.save("DUMMY1.xlsx")

xfile = xl.load_workbook('DUMMY1.xlsx')

# Load 100000 rows and 10 columns
sheet = xfile['Sheet']
for i in range(100001):
    for j in range(10):
        sheet.cell(row=i+1, column=j+1).value = "Hello "+str(i+1+j+1)
xfile.save('DUMMY2.xlsx')
```

**Performance Testing:**

```
import timeit
import openpyxl as xl
import pandas as pd
def func1():
    xl1 = xl.load_workbook("DUMMY2.xlsx")
    return xl1

def func2():
    df = pd.read_excel("DUMMY2.xlsx")
    return df

print(timeit.timeit('func1()', globals=globals(), number=1))
print(timeit.timeit('func2()', globals=globals(), number=1))
```

**Results:**

```
40.4193192
19.396849500000002
```

As you can see, **loading an excel file using openpyxl takes more than double as much time as loading using pandas**. If you load using xlrd and pandas combined, it is even little faster than loading to a pandas dataframe

Comment: Pandas can't be faster for this use case because it has to convert a worksheet into dataframe.

Comment: @CharlieClark thank you for the comment. But in my experience loading to a pandas dataframe has taken less than half the time taken to load using openpyxl. Using xlrd and pandas together makes the loading even faster. I have provided some test sameple and test results above. Please let me know if I am missing something. Happy to be proven wrong and learn from peer.

Comment: @CharlieClark could you please help me understand why in the above test or any such comparison test I have run before gave me better performance with pandas than openpyxl? I want to understand what I am missing and learn from it.

Comment: Look at the benchmarks in the documentation. The basic principle is OOXML  - openpyxl is less work than OOXML (rows) - Pandas (columns) - openpyxl (dict) but it all depends on how you optimise.

Answer (score 1):

You can loop through all rows and then directly access the cell in this row and in the first column:

```py
for rowNumber in range(1, sheet.max_row + 1):
    print(sheet.cell(row=rowNumber, column=1).value)
```

Comment: 2 corrections would be required here: 1> a row number has to start from 1, so it should be row=rowNumber+1, 2> sheet.cell() will just return the cell object and not the value of the cell, so  .value  needs to be added at the end.

Comment: I see that you have edited the answer to range(1, sheet.max_row) now. But that will exclude the last row of the excel. So, you have to rather make it  range(1, sheet.max_row+1) if you want to keep this part same:  cell(row=rowNumber, column=1)